# cyystal reports- setting currency symbol via globalisation (C# winforms)

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

I have more that 50 reports in my project hence i cannot opt to pass currency symbol to each and every report individually hence i am exploring an alternative to it, i have already set culture symbol to what i need but i am unable to set my crystal reports to accept that symbol.

for your better understanding i have a field in my db that accepts currency symbol and i have set current culture currency symbol to that value but i am unaware of how to set all my crystal reports to accept that value as my default currency symbol, also i would like to request a detailed step by step solution to this problem since i am new to crystal reports.

for alternatives i have currency symbol in an enum, db, culture, any short way of solving this problem is appreciated as in where i wont have to pass values to crystal reports individually, passing them through either formula might be considerable but i wish to set the fields to currency type and let the framework handle the rest for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a Parameter formula field to take the value and bring it on the Report by sending Value

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
Imports TimexSageEvoReportsWriter.clsEvoRequired

Private Const crParameterCurrency As String = "CurrencyCode"
Dim CrystlRpt As New ReportDocument
Dim myParameterFields As ParameterFields  
CrystlRpt.FileName = reportPath
myParameterFields = CrystlRpt.ParameterFields
myParameterFields.Item(0).CurrentValues.Clear()
Dim currentParameterValues As ParameterValues = New ParameterValues()
            Dim thisParameterField As ParameterField = myParameterFields(crParameterCurrency)
            If thisParameterField.PromptingType = DiscreteOrRangeKind.DiscreteValue Then
                Dim myParameterDiscreteValue As ParameterDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
                myParameterDiscreteValue.Value = myArrayList(0)(0).ToString()
                currentParameterValues.Add(myParameterDiscreteValue)
            End If
crViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = CrystlRpt
```

Only I have to get a formula to make this appear in the Currency Symbol of the Fields, for now I have placed the Currency Code near the Amount Field to appear like a formatted  amount , and made the symbol to be blank in Crystal manually.